# When a person jumps from boat does friction force between person feet and boat surface moves the boat backward or the force applied by the person?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, free-body-diagram

[image]

Force acting on person when jumping from boat is denoted by red colour and force acting on boat is denoted by yellow colour. I have not included the buoyant force and boat weight force on the boat.

Coming back to my question:-

The force applied by the person on the boat(F)can I Say it friction force which moves the boat in backwards direction and in reaction force acts on person feet can also be called friction force??

Or it some other kind of force like muscular force which moves the boat in backwards and person in forward??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The force applied by the person on the boat(F)can I Say it friction
> force which moves the boat in backwards direction and in reaction
> force acts on person feet can also be called friction force??

Yes you can say that. You can also say the forces are equal and opposite per Newton's 3rd law.

> Or it some other kind of force like muscular force which moves the
> boat in backwards and person in forward??

The energy that accelerates the boat backwards and accelerates the person forwards come from the work done by the persons muscles (from the person's internal energy). But the forces that enable the accelerations to occur are the equal and opposite friction forces.

Hope this helps.